# Is there any danger in allowing users to host PDF/RTF/DOC files on my web server?

Tags: exploit, web-hosting

If I were to allow users to host arbitrary PDF/RTF/DOC files on my server all under the same name, but with different query strings would there be anything to worry about? I've heard of PDF/RTF exploits, and I get that someone could perhaps host one of those on my server, but I mean it's not like they can access cookie data or anything through a PDF file. So is this fine to do, or should I be worried?

Should I have them host the files under a different domain name, or am I fine using my original domain?

I've noticed, for example, that a lot of websites like Facebook, Google, YouTube etc. have special domain names for hosting images and other data they allow users to upload, so I'm curious.

Comment: Facebook, Google _et al_ uses another domain for static content because the servers hosting images can be lightweight servers, not a full-blown webserver. And they can host static content all around the world.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Oh ok, so then would it be fine of me to allow users to upload pdf/rtf/doc files under my domain?

Comment: In reference to abacabadabacaba's comment, review this video: vimeo.com/103938583 A simple jpg upload functionality contributed to an internal domain controller being compromised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not that the files could contain exploits, but that they can be made to cause harm when reinterpreted as a different format. For example, someone may upload a file with RTF extension, which is actually a Flash file which is designed to steal cookies or perform CSRF attacks. That's one of the reasons Google [hosts all user-provided files on a separate domain](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2012/08/content-hosting-for-modern-web.html), so that the main domain is isolated from such content by [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Immediate danger - no.

Potential danger - yes: to anyone's system who is accessing these files. Virus scanning can mitigate some of this risk but is far from perfect.